# ViewPager performance issue due to invalitadion of every fragment inside

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager

Offtopic: thank you for your time and sorry for my English.

The problem is the lag when swiping on `ViewPager`.

The configuration used is a `TabHost` with Tabs (and dummy content), `ViewPager` with four fragments and `FragmentPagerAdapter` to manage it.

All 4 fragments have a list, some with other widgets in the layout. The thing is 2 fragments, or the 2 list in those fragments are quite heavy. The list items are `LinearLayout` with ~10 weighted items inside binded with a `CursorAdapter`. I know here resides the big problem, but I have struggled my small head to get an approach to this "percentage width" list item without any luck.

But, after some logs, I have figured out that the 3 managed fragments are "invalidated" during every swipe. I mean "invalidated" because what I see is every list binding items many ( a lot of ) times. And because of the redrawing of the 3 list, including my 2 heavy lists, the lag occurs.

2 things more to point of my code: I'm using cursor loaders, that I'm sure are not the cause of recreation because loader callbacks aren't arise on swipe. 
On `FragmentPagerAdapter.onPageSelected` I'm only updating the current tab.

Setting `ViewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit`(3) to keep 4 fragments alive do things worse. Even when I swipe from fragment 3 to 4, the list on first fragment is re-rendered, what I really don't want and don't understand.

My workaround is using the `onPageSelected` to set the visibility of current list view to Visible and the others hidden. With these approach the lag disappears (let's say 95%), but I can see, when I scroll the empty list view before is created.

I would like to ask, if I'm wrong at some point, maybe missing an important idea. If anyone has a possible solution, maybe avoiding those recreations (I don't know how) or, if other people is getting same, and there is nothing to do to solve it.

I will try to take I look to `ViewPager` source, but I've just opened the file woouu..
I will try to get a test project with this issue.

Thank you very much.